# Make object from a clone

Tags: mesh, objects

Hi again i will try my best with my broken english to explain :

I have a Plane and Sphere, i link both with the plane as parent and the sphere as child.
After i use in Object Tab the Duplication (faces), so  i have as result a clone (the second sphere).

So now i would like to make a object from this clone (make duplicates real) and work on it, like a new mesh.

For that i have selected the parent (the plane) and do  **Shift+Ctrl+A**  and as you can you on the last screenshot i have on the left menu " make duplicates real"  but what do i need to do now?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please do not ask the same question again. You could of edited your original with the extra information here.

Comment: Sorry i wanted delete the other one i didnt find how to do it....

Answer (score 0):

Ok i got it, i needed to do Maj+Ctrl+A just after have made the duplication.
Im not sure to be clear again with my english but i hope it will help someone not just myself ^^

[image]